# How to set JNI dependency when using moduleName in ndk{}?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working in Android Studio 2.1.2 with Gradle 2.10 and the experimental plugin 0.7.2. I'm trying to link a shared library to my JNI source files. I was looking over the experimental plugin [docs](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Multiple-NDK-Projects) and the [hello-lib](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs) sample.

The Hello-lib app/build.gradle has this part in it:

```
android.ndk {
    platformVersion = 21
    moduleName = 'hello-libs'
    toolchain = 'clang'
    stl = 'gnustl_static'
    cppFlags.addAll(['-std=c++11'])
    ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
    // build a default combined apk including all ABIs.
    // abiFilters.addAll(['x86'])
}
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            dependencies {
                library 'gmath' linkage 'shared'
                // if gperf were *.a, change shared --> static
                library 'gperf' linkage 'shared'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I did something similar, my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

def jniDir = "src/main/jni/"
def nLibDir = "src/main/jniLibs/"
model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            RAWExtractor {
                headers.srcDir = "${nLibDir}include"
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("${nLibDir}${targetPlatform.getName()}/libRAWExtractor.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        buildToolsVersion = "24.0.0"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "xyz.jamescarroll.layer"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName = 'jni'
            stl = 'gnustl_shared'
            platformVersion = 21
            toolchain = "clang"
            cppFlags.addAll(['-v', '-std=c++11', '-fexceptions'])
            ldFlags.addAll(['-I' + file("/src/main/jniLibs/include"),
                            '-L' + file("${nLibDir}")])
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log'])
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "RAWExtractor" linkage 'shared'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
            }
        }
        productFlavors {
            // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
            // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
            create("arm") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            }
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            }
            create("arm8") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            }
            create("x86") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
            }
            create("x86-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
            }
            create("mips") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
            }
            create("mips-64") {
                ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
            }
            // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
            create("all")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.3'
    compile 'uk.co.markormesher:android-fab:1.2.1'
}
```

My issue is that with something inside main{jni{}} and a moduleName inside ndk{} I get during gradle sync:

```
Error:No such property: srcDir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet
Possible solutions: srcDirs
```

I have no idea why this is happening and I've been trying to research this but I haven't been able to find anything with this and the newer plugin. If I comment out everything inside main{jni{}} or the moduleName I can sync the project, but then other parts break.

Project Structure (not enough rep to link to image):

```
|app
    |src
        |main
            |jni
                jni.c
                // etc
            |jniLibs
                |{platform} // (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, etc.)
                    libRAWExtractor.so
```

Does anyone know how to set a dependency and moduleName? Or, does anyone know how to link a shared library using the experimental plugin 0.7.2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change this DSL statement

`headers.srcDir = "${nLibDir}include"`

to

`headers.srcDir "${nLibDir}include"`